# PHP string variables not entering into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, variables, input

Having some issues with this line of code:

```
$usersql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO tp_request (user_id, week_no, floor, code) VALUES ($insertuser, $week, $floor, $code)");
```

Variable values are as follows:

```
$insertuser = 1;
$week = 4;
$floor = "First";
$code = "ABC123";
```

Both $insertuser and $week go into the database without issue when used together *without* the other two variables. However, when $floor and $code are used, nothing gets entered into the database. They both echo correctly on their own as "First" and "ABC123" respectively.

The fields in the database have been tried as both Text and VarChar and it's not working with either of these.

Any ideas on how to get $floor and $code to work here?

Comment: stings need to be quoted

Comment: using something like mysqli and prepared statements would automatically handle this for you as well as sanitize your input.

Comment: So it should be: `INSERT INTO tp_request (user_id, week_no, 'floor', 'code')` ?

Comment: All your problems would be fixed if this code wasn't incredibly insecure and hackable. 1. Don't use `mysql_`. It's an old extension, and it's deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead. 2. Use prepared statements and bind variables, or at *least* use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to avoid all these problems.

Comment: Stackoverflow needs to automatically reject any posts with `mysql_*()` with links to `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: @Populus You'd think from a site with thousands of programmers someone would've made a bot already!

Comment: Funny, I kind of had the same thought some time back; being that an automatic message gets posted, then going straight to [`this page`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) @Populus

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Added `'` to wrap around the variables `$floor` and `$code` since it contains  strings,

```
$usersql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO tp_request (user_id, week_no, floor, code) 
 VALUES ($insertuser, $week, '$floor', '$code')");
```

**NOTE:** use mysqli_* functions or PDO instead of using mysql_* functions(deprecated)

Comment: Beat me to it. @user910930 You're breaking the SQL syntax by not wrapping strings in quotes.

Comment: why are you quoting the integers?

Comment: @dagon why does it matter? Technically it isn't needed because they're integers, but it's just good practice in case they're not.

Comment: its bad practice because they are not. any future programmer will seeing this code will amuse they are strings, and process them as such, when they are in fact integers.

Comment: *"A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools."*. Safe is better than sorry. If he ever replaces the `var` with a string instead, the SQL can remain.

Comment: @kcdwayne Your database would fail if you input a string and it assumes an INT, so it's not any better. If anything, don't use quotes, and make sure to cast it to an int before you paste it into your query.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite like

```
  $usersql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tp_request` (`user_id`, `week_no`, `floor`, `code`) VALUES ('$insertuser', '$week', '$floor', $code)");
```

Sidenote : You need to stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Switch to PreparedStatements.

Comment: why are you quoting the integers and why are you using `` smart quotes at all?

Comment: +1 for side note. PDO is more secure, unless you're into SQL injections.

Comment: I really think "fixing" code like this is actually a bad thing, as when it's broken it's not a vector someone could crack into your site with. It's like "My gun is jammed, help me fix it so I can shoot myself in my foot!"

Answer (score 0):

```
 $usersql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO tp_request (user_id, week_no, floor, code) VALUES ($insertuser, $week, '$floor', '$code')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add single quotes to you sql clause around string variables.